# Ravendb multimapindex incomplete result

Tags: c#, ravendb

I am new to RavenDB. I am trying to create a multimapindex in RavenDB and below is one of the maps:

```
this.AddMap<ProposedData>(proposedDatas =>
                                        from psd in proposedDatas
                                        let pgds = psd.PropertyGroupValues.Select(pgv => this.LoadDocument<PropertyGroupDefinition>($"PropertyGroupDefinitions/{pgv.DefinitionId}"))
                                        let propertyDefs = pgds.SelectMany(pgd => pgd.PropertyDefinitions)
                                        let propertyVals = psd.PropertyGroupValues.SelectMany(pgv => pgv.PropertyValues.SelectMany(pv => propertyDefs.Where(pd => pd.Id == pv.DefinitionId).Select(pd => new { Value = this.AsDocument(pv).Value<object>("Value"), TagName = pd.TagName })))
                                        from property in propertyVals
                                        select new Result
                                        {
                                            Id = psd.Id.ToString().Replace("ProposedDatas/", ""),
                                            HasApprovedVersion = false,
                                            Value = property.Value, 
                                            TagName = property.TagName
                                        });
```

It does create the index, but does not include all the Value and TagName. But when I use

```
Value = propertyVals.Select(pv => pv.TagName),
```

instead, it has the complete list of TagName I am looking for. I am using RavenDB v3. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Below is my result structure:

```
public class Result
    {
        public bool HasApprovedVersion { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }
        public string TagName { get; set; }
    }
```

P.S I tried to use join, but got an exception.

Thanks.

Comment: For those who are curious, the exception that is thrown when I use join is AggregateException "Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type"

Comment: Is it not possible to write 2 'from' in the query?

Answer (score 0):

It is not advisable to write two froms, but it is supported. The likely issue is the complexity of the index, because we are trying to reconstruct what you meant on the other side.
In general, it is better to avoid using fanout and have a single entry per document.